# Prove that the sequence defined recursively converges.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

statement of the problem:
Given a positive number b and a set $E \subseteq  R$, let us say that a function $f : E \rightarrow R$ has property $X(b)$ on $E$ provided that for each pair $x, y \in E$ , $ |f(y) - f(x)| \leq  b|y-x|  $

Suppose $f$ maps the open interval $E$ into itself, $0 < b < 1$, $f$ has property $X(b)$, and
$x_0 \in E$ Prove that the sequence $\{ x_k \}$ defined recursively by $x_k = f(x_{k−1})$ for $k \geq 1$
converges.

This is the work I have written attempting the proof so far:

Given: $x_0 \in E$ $f(x_{k-1}) = x_k$ $0 < b <1$, $f$ has the property $X(b) \in E$, $|f'(x)| \leq b$, $x_0 \in E$

from $|f'(x)| \leq b$

$f(x_0) - f(x) \leq y+x_1$ becomes $f(x_0) = x_1$

$x_k = f(x_{k-1})$. for $ K\geq 1$

then $x_k = x_0 \forall k$ and the sequence converges.

is this right?

Comment: Btw, the property () is known as Lipschitz continuity

Comment: @Ll  Yes, I know that now that I see it. But in most places and books I know it is called "A Lipschitz Function", not "property "$X(b)$"

Comment: @LLcoolJ: Do you need E to be bounded? For example, $f(x) = x+1$ satisfies Lipschitz, and maps $(0,\infty)\subseteq \mathbb R$ to $(0,\infty)\subseteq \mathbb R$, but does not converge?

Comment: I think the gist here is that this is a contraction mapping, and that for any x in E the iterated function sequence x, f (x), f (f (x)), f (f (f (x))), ... converges to the fixed point.